# use aspx page and web.config with a new domain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used a new domain. When I set only html pages than site running correct. 
But when I use web.config and aspx page then site give an error.

Error is : HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: If you have remote access to that server, logon and access the page over localhost, IIS will show some debug information. That should help you. This is impossible to answer without seeing your web.config

Answer (score 0):

You may first check whether web.config is well-formed, next you may change customError's mode to off like the following snippet

```
<customErrors mode="off" />
```

The above would reveal any error details related to your aspx or code-behind.